# Pixel 4a - Can't find ARCore even though it says it's already downloaded

Tags: android, arcore

Pixel 4a comes with ARCore and is on the list of supported devices

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

However when I'm trying to load the ArFragment

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/ar_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

It keeps prompting me to download ARCore and when I go try to find ARCore in the playstore, it's not there.

Can't seem to find any info about this issue googling it.

Comment: I have just tested an AR app on Pixel 4a and it worked without issue - can you share details of the error?

Comment: @Mick it's a weird issue but my app was not detecting ARCore until I changed the targetSDK version from 30 to 29.

Comment: I see the same thing on Pixel 4XL and tried turning back to sdk version 29 and was working on 29, don't work on 30. Does anyone knows what changed to this stop working?

Comment: Same here, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `targetSdkVersion` was `30`, after changing it to `targetSdkVersion 29` the ARcore library was being detected.

Comment: it sucks because sceneform is deprecated, probably this will be an ongoing issue? I don't see any support happening here :(

Comment: @dirty-dave Unable to publish in playstore since min target sdk version is 30 . Do u  have any solution for this armodule ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be related to the fact that Sceneform is not compatible with the latest target SDK version (30)

**Sceneform was targeting ARCore 1.16** when it was archived while **ARCore current version is 1.27**!

Since ARCore has it own decoupled Service installed on the device:
[Google Play Services for AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core)

Just like for Google Play Services, there is a time when old applications targeting old versions of the service don't work anymore.

See [AR sceneform activity crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388567/ar-sceneform-activity-crashes) for another example of a crash looking like yours (also related to this Sceneform issue).

Your alternatives to Sceneform include:

> - [ARCore SDK for Android](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk): Scratch Sceneform and work directly with ARCore, but that would require you to work with OpenGL.
> - [Google ARCore SDK for Unity](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk): If you know about Unity
> - [Sceneform Maintained Android SDK](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk): [a repository which I maintain] Based on Sceneform with latest compatibly and functionalities from Android (including androidx**), ARCore and Filament. Currently a small community is working on it to keep it up to date and to develop new features.

<sup>⠀⠀⠀⠀Quoted from [Sceada's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4564449/sceada) answer to: "[Sceneform Dependencies for 1.16.0 (Not AndroidX Compatible)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69522173)", copyright 2021-10-11, which has been modified to indicate that I maintain Sceneform Maintained Android SDK.</sup>

I also suggest you to have a look at the article I wrote, [Make an Android AR app in 2022](https://medium.com/make-an-android-ar-augmented-reality-app-for/make-an-ar-augmented-reality-app-for-android-in-2022-48a1711562bb), which gives an overview of Sceneform Maintained Android SDK, the Sceneform alternative I maintain.

Comment: When posting links to resources to which you have an affiliation, you are [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose your affiliation in the post. Otherwise, your post may be considered spam. Please [edit] your post to include your affiliation. Please also have a look at [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @IanCampbell In the meantime, I've fixed the issue of a lack of affiliation being disclosed.