# Android Emulator SDK--30 is not working with AR application [Google sceneform sdk]

Tags: android, android-emulator, arcore, sceneform

We are developing an AR application with google-sceneform sdk, the app is getting crashed on Android 11 (**Real Device**) after the successful launch. we are able to identify the plane and place an object but after some time it will crash.

So we are trying it on emulator sdk-30. But after running the application it shows **Failed to create AR Session**.
I have followed the whole steps provided by Google in this [Link](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator) but it didn't work.
Tried all the steps with android studio 4.1 and **SDK-30** with emulator version 30.2.6 which is **not worked**.
The normal hand sign for scanning the surface is also not shown.

But with **SDK-27** it worked. We need the sdk-30 to be worked.

**Q1:** is the emulator failing issue is a known issue? did anyone faced this before?

**This is the log for Emulator.**

```
2020-12-28 16:38:58.742 7153-7153/com.quintar.myapplication E/StandardArFragment: Error: Failed to create AR session
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:391)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338)

#### SKIPPING SOME LINES HERE ####

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException: Failed to launch installer.
    at com.google.ar.core.p.b(InstallService.java:53)
    at com.google.ar.core.p.a(InstallService.java:40)
    at com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity.startInstaller(InstallActivity.java:116)
    at com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity.access$200(InstallActivity.java:125)
    at com.google.ar.core.k.onClick(InstallActivity.java:3)

#### SKIPPING SOME LINES HERE ####

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.ar.core }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
```

**Q2:** it is very much appreciatable if anyone can help me to fix the on Android 11 crash issue.

**this is crash log on Android 11** **(Real device**)

```
2020-12-21 14:19:01.868 14629-14629/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when         
deallocating address 0x0073944b2ea0
'
2020-12-21 14:19:02.415 14629-14629/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00000000000431bc  
/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so 
(scudo::reportInvalidChunkState(scudo::AllocatorAction, void*)+76) (BuildId: 
95f68a34fdf7b31f42d3f811d5d88f58)
2020-12-21 14:19:03.665 1091-6178/? E/AudioSystem: invalid attributes { Content type: 
AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN Usage: AUDIO_USAGE_UNKNOWN Source: -1 Flags: 0x800 Tags:  } when 
converting to stream
2020-12-21 14:19:06.839 895-1615/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: 
invalid input device 0x0, for event 2
```

Comment: Yup I've also had this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/65299748/11110509
Have to change the target sdk version to 29 and lower to fix

Answer (score 0):

In file `'YourProject/app/build.gradle'` set the next dependecies for Android Target API 30 with the last of AR Sceneform Library:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
    }
}
dependencies {
  ...
  api "com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.17.1"
  api "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1"
  api "com.google.ar:core:1.22.0"
  ...
}
```