# AR sceneform activity crashes

Tags: android, augmented-reality, sceneform

I am having an issue with AR using sceneform 1.5. The activity containing the AR sometimes crashes (white screen) and goes back to the activity that started it. Sometimes, I'm able to display the 3D model however when I move the camera, the activity crashes. I already tried to debug but the logs are being cleared and also no crashes registered on the play console. This issue is intermittent and I mostly encounter it in our Samsung A7,S9 and Huawei P20 test devices. I haven't encountered the issue on Note 9 and S21. What are the possible cause of the crash?

Comment: We need more context. You should show us the code you are using. What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version of Sceneform. I would suggest to update to the latest community maintained version of Sceneform

- [Sceneform update and alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69522173/4564449)

Comment: Shifting to a different version of Sceneform will not solve this person's issue. The older versions of Sceneform work fine and it depends on the kind of code this person is writing. We need more context.

Comment: I don't fully agree, there is a bug in the old version of Sceneform which leads to a random app crash. And the described behaviour smells like that.

Comment: Can you link to the bug report?

Comment: Here is the discussion on the maintained repository https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/SceneformMaintained/discussions/110

This bug is now fixed. @user2385014 pls post a stacktrace