# Drawing multiple AR objects with openGL ES

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, augmented-reality

The tutorial I'm following is [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-cloud-anchors#0).What I wonder is:Can I add another AR object in the scene?Also,Can I make it point to any cloud anchor I want?Since I'm new to openGL ES(Some idea say that in sceneform it will be easier,is that true?)I want to know how to do it.If there's any other idea to these questions,please tell me.
[what I want to made will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ryti.png)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the new maintained Version of [Sceneform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69522173/4564449). OpenGL is awesome but it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: so use sceneform + ARcore is easier then use openGL?If it is,I'll try to convert my project to sceneform.

Comment: You can checkout the Sceneform Repository and the linked medium article to see if it fit your needs.